# In Play Framework for Java, when a controller returns a Promise<Result>, how to modify headers?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka-http

My goal is to implement a controller method that depends and on a potentially lengthy operation, a HTTP request. I learned that controllers should be non-blocking and that I can [return a Promise](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaAsync) instead of a result:

```
public F.Promise<Result> demo() {
    final F.Promise<WSResponse> upstreamResponse = WS.url(SOME_ENDPOINT).get();
    F.Promise<Result> ourResult = upstreamResponse.map(new F.Function<WSResponse, Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result apply(WSResponse wsResponse) {
            final String body = someMethod(wsResponse);
            final Map<String, String> headers = otherMethod(wsResponse);
            // What do I do with headers?
            return ok(body);
        }
    });
    return ourResult;
}
```

Using this method, we can specify the body, optionally the Content-Type and Status code. However, we cannot add additional Customer headers.

In a controller method that returns a plain Result, we can use

```
        response().setHeader(name, value);
```

How do I achieve the same effect in the asynchronous code above?

Note: I'm new to the Play Framework and will accept any other solution to set the response headers.

Comment: Sorry this might be a bit of a useless comment since I only use the Scala API, but that API has a `Ok("Hello world").withHeaders(ETAG -> "0")` method. Maybe there is something similar in the Java API?

Comment: @JamieP Thanks for your hint: `ok().toScala().withHeaders(headers)` returns an instance of `play.api.mvc.Result`. Typically Java controller methods return `play.mvc.Result`. This is tempting. However, as total beginner, I cannot just whether we are on the right track here.

Comment: This is a bit dated but might help - https://gist.github.com/joergviola/3923363